# How do i plot pair of points from an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I have a matrix:

```
img = [1 1 2 2 
       1 1 2 2 
       3 2 2 2 
       3 2 2 2 
       3 3 3 2];
```

from which I obtained the array of points:

```
A = [3 2; 5 4];
```

I need to plot each pair of points (y,x) row-by-row `(i.e (3,2), (5,4), etc)` and i have tried the code:

```
for i = 1: size(A, 2)
    plot(A(i, 1), A(i, 2), '*')     
end
```

This however does not give the expected positions of the points. Please, what could be wrong with my code and what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your pairs of points are in `row/column` order, you'll need to switch the order for `plot` as the order of inputs to `plot` are `x/y`. Also, you'll want to use the number of rows `size(A, 1)` rather than `size(A, 2)`

```
for k = 1:size(A, 1)    
    plot(A(k,2), A(k,1), '*')
    hold on
end
```

You can also just plot everything at once without the loop

```
plot(A(:,2), A(:,1), '*');
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Suever.